# Conditional 'static' to 'fixed' on div causing scrolling jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a top navigation bar that has position: "static", but when a user scrolls past the height of the navigation bar, the position changes to "fixed", so that the navigation bar attaches to the top of the window. It also switches back to "static" when scrolling back to the top of the page.

The navigation bar has a static banner div that remains at the top of the page. When the top of the window scrolls below the navigation bar, it changes to position: "fixed".

I've been experiencing some jitter when the page is just barely long enough to require scrolling, but not enough to keep the scroll height and navigation bar as "fixed", so when scrolling to the bottom of the page, the navigation bar jitters between "static" and "fixed".

I've posted the jsfiddle of how I have it set up, but not quite able to replicate the problem as I'm experiencing it: http://jsfiddle.net/bB7Bf/

HTML:

```
<div id="topMaterial">Static Top doesn't move</div>
<div id="ktNavbar">topbar that sticks to top of window after scrolls below static height</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
var navScroll = $(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPosition > 120) $("#ktNavbar").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "right": 0
    });

    else $("#ktNavbar").css("position", "static");
    });
});​
```

Is there a workaround to prevent this scrolling conditional jitter between "static" and "fixed"?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep it fixed the whole time and add a top margin on whatever content is underneath? No js necessary.

Comment: I like this idea, simple and effective.

Comment: I have a static banner bar that will remain at the top of the page and the navigation bar sits below it. Once the top of the window scrolls below the bottom of the static navbar, it sticks to the top of the window as fixed. Just like the blue/white navigation table for Twitter Bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html